# Templated Function Pointer in C++

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I am facing a problem with templated member function pointer.
The code is as shown below.

```
#include <String>
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
struct method_ptr
{
    typedef void (T::*Function)(std::string&);
};

template <class T>
class EventHandler
{
private:
    method_ptr<T>::Function m_PtrToCapturer;
};
```

e:\EventHandler.h(13) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_PtrToCapturer'

I am facing this error.

Even If I use

```
method_ptr<EventHandler>::Function m_PtrToCapturer;
```

as member variable I am getting same error as above.

Comment: Please show the *actual* problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: What does "create a variable of this type" refer to?! *Which* type?

Comment: Sorry Guys I have a limitation here I can't use C++11 compiler as my project does not entertain it right now. And the actual problem is I want to create a variable of templated function pointer, so that I can store it and call it on some event. ANd while creating the variable I have to use the template <typename T> instead of class name as it can be used by any class. Hope the problem is clear...

Comment: No, that's not clear at all. Please present a very short demo (pseudo-code if necessary) of what you would like to write, and indicate the line about which you're unsure (hopefully there's only one).

Comment: @TechTotie As I know, in C++98, you should use extra struct... that's why there is template typedef/using in cpp11

Comment: suck! stackoverflow steals my sleeping time! morning is coming and I haven't slept.. I'd rather sleep than anything..

Comment: To be specific the problem ,I want to store the function pointer that comes to me from any class. How do I do it? I wont be aware of which class will be calling it. Like... I am trying this template <class T> method_ptr<T>::Function m_PtrToMemFunc; where T is unknown. It may be Class A calling passing its member function like method_ptr<Class A>::Function m_PtrToMemFunc; or Class B like method_ptr<Class B>::Function m_PtrToMemFunc; I wont be knowing which class will be passing its pointer. Like ikh said should I make my class a templated class in this case or is there any other way?

Comment: @TechTotie: No, no, no, *please* edit your original post to make it self-contained and readable. Look around you, and note how well-formatted other questions are. Spend some time editing everything into shape. You have a live preview to guide you.

Comment: @Kerrek: I have re-framed the entire question. Let me know if this is precise and understandable. Sorry to post code in the comment. I thought it would get indented automatically. Will not post code in comments any further..

Comment: @TechTotie: Cool, thanks. Now I think I know what your question is (and if I'm right, then there are *thousands* of duplicates of this extremely common issue on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `method_ptr<T>::Function` is a *dependent name* (dependent on `T`), you need to disambiguate it with `typename`:

```
template <class T>
class EventHandler
{
private:
    typename method_ptr<T>::Function m_PtrToCapturer;
//  ^^^^^^^^
};
```

Comment: `typedef typename method_ptr<T>::Function PFunction` will make code more readability.

Comment: Sorry to open this thread again. How do I call the function. I tried m_PtrToCapturer("Hello"); But results in error "error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments" Please help...

Comment: @TechTotie: You need to supply a suitable object on which to call the member function. *Any* tutorial on pointers to member functions will tell you how the syntax works.

Comment: @Kerrek: Thanks for your response. I have class Evenhandler's object EventHandler *evthndlr; It is initaliased too. I was trying to call this function pointer like evthndlr->m_PtrToCapturer("Hello"); But was getting error.... Any suggestions...

Comment: @TechTotie: Yes, same as before: Read some tutorials on member function pointers. It should be `(evthndlr->*m_PtrToCapturer)("Hello")`.

Answer (score 0):

This works,

```
struct method_ptr
{
    typedef void (T::*Function)(std::string&);
};

template <class T>
class EventHandler
{

private:
    typename method_ptr<T>::Function m_PtrToCapturer;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Since C++11, you can use `using`.

```
template <typename T>
using Function = void (T::*)(std::string);
```

(By the way, why is `std::string` called-by-value? I recommend `const std::string &`.)

---

Aha, I figured out your second question.

```
template <typename T>
method_ptr<T>::Function m_PtrToMemFunc; //<--
```

template is only applied to *class and function* (and cpp11's typedef&using...). you should write like this.

```
method_ptr<SomeClass>::Function m_PtrToMemFunc;
```

Comment: @Kerrek Beacuse I'm on phone, I can't... Even if my code has error, maybe it's just my mistype..

Comment: Please don't post answers from a phone. That's the definition of "phoning it in".

Comment: @KerrekSB please elaborate on why this is bad. Some people don't have a `C++11` compiler and would want to know why the question is downvoted, for future reference.

Comment: @PawełStawarz: Half of it it flat-out wrong. The other half probably doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @ikh Your last edit is exactly what OP does. His issue is with using that pattern afterwards. But your usage example might be relevant.

Comment: @ikh: The first sentence is flat-out fabricated. *Please* verify this sort of stuff. You can even use an online compiler to do a basic smoke test.

Comment: Thanks Guys for your support. Further details on my requirements are specified in the above comment...

Comment: @KerrekSB I forgot WEB COMPILER!! and you're right, I had some error: template `typedef` can't be used to make member function pointer type, `using` is allowed. thank you so much!

Comment: @ikh Thanks for your answer. 
If I have templated class like 
template<class T> 
class EventHandler
{ 
 struct method_ptr
 {
  typedef void (T::*Function)(std::string);
 };
 private:
 method_ptr<T>::Function m_PtrToCapturer;

};
I still face errors saying 
 error C2059: syntax error : '<'
        e:\project\EventHandler.h(13) : see reference to class template instantiation 'EventHandler<T>' being compiled
 error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' Any idea where am I going wrong again

Comment: @TechTotie You need `typename method_ptr<T>::Function m_PtrToCapturer;`. Also, make sure you have the include for method_ptr.