# Template Fn Pointer error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, member-variables

I am facing a problem with templated member function pointer. The code is as shown below.

```
#include <String>
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
struct method_ptr
{
    typedef void (T::*Function)(std::string&);
};

template <class T>
class EventHandler
{
private:
    method_ptr<T>::Function m_PtrToCapturer;
};
```

e:\EventHandler.h(13) :

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_PtrToCapturer'
```

I am facing this error.

Even If I use

```
method_ptr<EventHandler>::Function m_PtrToCapturer;
```

as member variable I am getting same error as above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Officially, what is typename for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600936/officially-what-is-typename-for)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863194/solved-templated-function-pointer-in-c/21890444#21890444

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which compiler you use. I compiled it using GCC. It suggests that 'typename' is put before the definition of m_PtrToCapturer.